# Adding rows in awk-output

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I'm using `awk` to write a bash script that outputs the count of error codes ranging from `400 - 500`  that appear in a text file called `output.txt`

```
awk '($9 >= 400)' output.txt | awk '{print $9}' | sort | uniq -c
```

The output of the above is:

```
  12 400
  11 401
  55 403
  91 404
  41 500
```

How do I add the first column together using bash so that in the example above, I get `210` instead of the above output... (12 + 11 + 55 + 91 + 41 = 210)

And if I wanted to input in a file via command line argument instead of `output.txt` how should I edit the script? I know that you use '$1' and '$2' to access command line arguments, but in this case how would it work considering I'm already using `$9` in with `awk`

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: When you say "concatenate" ITYM "add". When you concatenate `3` and `6` you get `36`, when you add `3` and `6` you get `9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your problem immediate since you are using already 1 command, could try as(though I am pretty sure if you could share sample of your input we could probably do it in a single command too):

```
your_command | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum}'
```

Also in OP's command part `awk '($9 >= 400)' output.txt | awk '{print $9}'` could be shorten to `awk '($9 >= 400){print $9}' output.txt`

Comment: And the whole pipeline can be: `awk '$9 > 400 {sum++} END {print sum}' output.txt`

Comment: @glennjackman, Sorry sir I apologies, I didn't quite understand it. May I request you to please do edit my answer for better  understand please.

Comment: hi @RavinderSingh13 how would you update the script so that it can will read from command line argument instead of `output.txt`. So i want to just call it like so`./statuscode.sh output.txt`

Comment: @sgeza, change in your script like, `var="$1"` and where in your command you are mentioning `output.txt` now put `"$var"` in its place. Lemme know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

To get `the count of error codes ranging from 400 - 500 that appear in a text file called output.txt` assuming each error code is in $9 is:

```
awk '($9 >= 400) && ($9 <= 500) && !seen[$9]++{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' output.txt
```

To get `the count of **lines containing** error codes ranging from 400 - 500 that appear in a text file called output.txt` assuming each error code is in $9 is:

```
awk '($9 >= 400) && ($9 <= 500){cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' output.txt
```